# tinyMCE + Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, tinymce

My problem now is that when I make arrangements to CodeIgniter :

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

This setting remove tags that I made in the TinyMCE editor

```
<img style="....">
```

As of now I can only do the setting

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

Then I use xss_filter to field I want.
It certainly makes me difficult if there are many forms that require validation this. Is there no other way to be able to recognize CodeIgniter style tag in TinyMCE?

Comment: What are "Codeigniter style tag"s ? Global xss filtering will destroy any html. What I can say, don't escape anything unless just before outputting on the page, html or js won't do any harm inside a db cell

Comment: @DamienPirsy : Means I have to keep using $config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have other option

set xss filtering false

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

then use second param for the input , if u need xss filtering on for specifc field

```
$name = $this->input->post('name', TRUE); // xss filtering on
```

if you dont want xss filtering

```
$tiny_mce = $this->input->post('tiny_mce'); // xss filtering off
```

<strike>**or i think you can do it in reverse**</strike>

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

and

```
$tiny_mce = $this->input->post('tiny_mce', FALSE); // xss filtering off
```

Comment: The solution may be like that and I've done .. :) I was hoping there might be another way

Comment: You can't do it in reverse. It does not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686074/codeigniter-2-and-how-to-disabled-xss-for-tinymce?rq=1