# codeigniter 2 and how to disabled xss for TinyMCE

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce, codeigniter-2

ive searched every site including stackoverflow on this issue.

I have XSS globally turned on and few pages I have use TinyMCE. On those pages I'd like the TinyMCE part to not have XSS enabled.

After reading about 40 pages, they all say to do the following:

```
$tiny_mce = $this->input->post('note'); // xss filtering off
```

or

```
$tiny_mce = $this->input->post('note', FALSE); // xss filtering off
```

I have tried both, here is my model:

```
public function edit($id) {

          $tiny_mce = $this->input->post('note'); // xss filtering off
          $userId = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
          $data = array(
                        'note' => $tiny_mce
                        ,'postedBy' => $userId);
          $this->db->where('id', $id);
          $this->db->update('company_notes', $data);

}
```

Anyone know why its not working? Any help would be great! I really dont want to globally turn XSS off, so im hoping for a "
per basis" approach.

**Edit**
I just tried

```
public function edit($id) {
          $this->config->set_item('global_xss_filtering', FALSE);
          $tiny_mce = $this->input->post('note'); // xss filtering off
          $userId = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
          $data = array(
                        'note' => $tiny_mce
                        ,'postedBy' => $userId);
          $this->db->where('id', $id);
          $this->db->update('company_notes', $data);

}
```

but that too doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to disable XSS filtering after Controller initialized.

Because if you enable `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` at `config.php` file, CodeIgniter Performs XSS filtering on `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_COOKIE` before initializing `Controllers`, `Models` and ...

So when you get access to `Controller` everything is done before.

While a solution is to disable `$config['global_xss_filtering']` and run XSS filtering on specific variables as you need, There's a way to keep the original values (pre-filtered) somewhere for using them later:

**1)** Set the `$config['enable_hooks']` to `TRUE` at `application/config.php`.

**2)** Insert the following into the `application/config/hooks.php`:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
    'class'    => '',
    'function' => 'keep_vars',
    'filename' => 'keep_vars.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => array($_POST, $_GET)
);
```

**Note:** We are using this [`Hook`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) to execute `keep_vars()` function before Controller initialized ( you might also want to consider using `'pre_system'` key).

**3)** Create `keep_vars.php` inside `application/hooks/` directory with the content below:

```
<?php

function keep_vars ($vars = array())
{
    if (empty($vars)) return;

    global $pre_filter;

    $pre_filter = array();

    foreach ($vars as $var) {
        $pre_filter = array_merge($pre_filter, $var);
    }
}
```

**4)** Finally, when you want to get access to a variable in `$_GET` or `$_POST` in your controller, define the global `$pre_filter` variable inside the method:

```
class Foo extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function bar ()
    {
        // define as global
        global $pre_filter;

        // check the pre XSS filtered values
        print_r($pre_filter);

        // you can get access to pre filtered $_POST['key'] by:
        echo $pre_filter['key'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the security documentation 3 more times, it occurs to me the security setting are applied when a new controller is invoked so using

`$this->config->set_item('global_xss_filtering', FALSE);`

in a controller won't work.  You can however use one of CI's [hooks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) to accomplish this.

the pre_controller hook looks like it should do the trick for you.

theres a pretty nice tutorial about halfway down the page [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/advanced-codeigniter-techniques-and-tricks/) that shows you how to override config items.  Its under the 'Serving Separate Response Formats' section.

So in your config/hooks.php file add this:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
   'class'     => 'the_name_of_your_controller',
   'function'  => 'config', //or the name of the function that will fire on preload
   'filename'  => 'the_file_name_of_your_controller.php',
   'filepath'  => 'hooks'                
);
```

THen in your controller add this function:

```
public function config() {
   $CI      =& get_instance();
   $CI->config->set_item( 'global_xss_filtering', FALSE );
}
```

Comment: @bnelsonjax out of curiosity, what exactly are you posting from TinyMCE?  I remember I also had an issue with having to htmlentities/htmlencode the posted content for proper storage and then decode it when displaying it wherever I displayed it.

Comment: @bnelsonjax  see my revised answer.  after a little digging it looks like you'll need to use hooks to accomplish this as security is applied before controller load.

Comment: i read that but couldnt make heads or tails out of it, im still rather new to CI and php for that matter. i guess i'll just turn XSS off globally

Comment: @bnelsonjax  I added some example code as to how you would approach it if you still want to give it a try.

Comment: @Rooster The `'class'` parameter doesn't belong to the `Controller` it refers to the Class name of hook file at `'filepath'/'filename'`; If a procedural function is used instead of a class, this item should left blank.