# change the cofiguration for required function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, configuration

I am working with codeigniter, using ckeditor for text editing, while saving the text into database the css effects are filtering,
If I changed the `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` in config.php file it working properly.

But I want to change it only for some functions

Otherwise it should be `$config['global_xss_filtering'] =TRUE` as written in config.php file

I am Using

```
$this->config->load('config');
$this->config->set_item('global_xss_filtering', FALSE);
```

but it is not working, please suggest me answer.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686074/codeigniter-2-and-how-to-disabled-xss-for-tinymce

Comment: In addition check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337143/codeigniter-why-use-xss-clean and look for rook's answer. 

TL;DR xss is an output problem not an input problem. Filtering on the input gives you a false sense of security and you are also corrupting data. Set global_xss_filtering to FALSE for good and just be a good programmer by knowing when to escape the output and when not to.

Comment: @IntegralWind-up you can link comments and answers too, see example: [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061241/change-the-cofiguration-for-required-function-in-codeigniter#comment42637117_27061241) and [Rook's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5346696/1564365)